# Brackets in JavaScript/React in Query Params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, query-string

How do I achieve the brackets as shown in this URL?

`{{url}}/invoices?orderBy[created_at]=asc&orderBy[reference_number]=asc`

[image: screenshot from Postman showing URL format]

**invoiceApi.js**

```
import api from '@/api/api';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const invoiceUrl = `/invoices`;

export const fetchInvoices = (
  {
    pageNumber,
    pageSize,
    search = '',
    orderBy = { created_at: 'asc', reference_number: 'asc' },
  },
  config
) => {
  const params = {
    page: pageNumber + 1,
    size: pageSize,
    search,
    orderBy, //  no spread syntax here
  };
  return api.get(invoiceUrl, {
    ...config,
    params: {
      ...config.params,
      ...params,
    },
  });
};

export const useFetchInvoicesQuery = (data) => {
  const { pageNumber, pageSize, search } = data;
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['invoices', pageNumber, pageSize, search],
    queryFn: () => fetchInvoices(data),
  });
};
```

**InvoiceAutocomplete.js**

```
import { useFetchInvoicesQuery } from '@/api/invoiceApi';
import { useDebounceValue } from '@/hooks/useDebounceValue';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function renderInvoiceAutocomplete(params) {
  return <InvoiceAutocomplete {...params} />;
}

const InvoiceAutocomplete = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue },
  ...props
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const debouncedInputValue = useDebounceValue(inputValue, 500);

  const { data: response, isLoading } = useFetchInvoicesQuery({
    pageNumber: 0,
    pageSize: 50,
    search: debouncedInputValue,
  });

  const handleChange = (_, newValue, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clear') {
      setFieldValue(field.name, { id: '', invoice_number: '' });
      setFieldValue('total_amount', undefined);
      return;
    }
    setFieldValue(field.name, newValue);
    setFieldValue('total_amount', newValue?.amount);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (_, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        typeof option === 'string' ? option : option?.invoice_number || ''
      }
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
        return (
          <li {...props} key={option.id}>
            {option?.invoice_number}
          </li>
        );
      }}
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={response?.data?.data || []}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      filterSelectedOptions
      noOptionsText={isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'No data'}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...props}
          error={touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] ? true : false}
          helperText={
            touched[field.name] &&
            errors[field.name] &&
            String(errors[field.name].id)
          }
        />
      )}
      fullWidth
    />
  );
};

InvoiceAutocomplete.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  form: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Are you using Axios? I ask because it has features to handle this use case specifically. If you're using `fetch()`, you have to handle it yourself

Comment: @Phil. I'm using axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios has features to handle this use case specifically.

Pass your query param data via the `params` option and it will automatically translate objects to use the square-bracket notation.

```js
const invoiceUrl = 'https://echo.zuplo.io/'; // just for the demo
const api = axios.create();

const fetchInvoices = (
  {
    pageNumber,
    pageSize,
    search = '',
    orderBy = { created_at: 'asc', reference_number: 'asc' },
  },
  config = {},
) => {
  const params = {
    page: pageNumber + 1,
    size: pageSize,
    search,
    orderBy, //  no spread syntax here
  };
  return api.get(invoiceUrl, {
    ...config,
    params: {
      ...config.params,
      ...params,
    },
  });
};

fetchInvoices({
  pageNumber: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
}).then(({ data }) => {
  console.log(data.url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm changing to this one seems not calling the API

 `return api.get(invoiceUrl, {
    ...config,
    params: {
      ...config.params,
      ...params,
    }
  });`

Comment: How are you calling `fetchInvoices`? Are you getting any errors? Perhaps you should default `config` to an empty object

Comment: I have updated my code above. No errors. Just no network request. Let me know if you need me to add more to my code

Comment: @Joseph I updated my answer. Your original code made it look like you always provided a `config` object